# Multiple Charts on single page RAZOR MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, highcharts

I want to show 2 charts on my page;

I tried to apply the code of this answer :[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428806/highcharts-multiple-charts-on-a-single-page-using-c-sharp-asp-net-mvc3)

but the page displays only the last chart added to the list

this is the view :

```
@model Project.Models.TableauDeBord
@using DotNet.Highcharts


@foreach (Highcharts chart in Model.Charts)
{

        @(chart)

}




@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/HighChart")
}
```

and action method :

```
public ActionResult TableauDeBord()

        {

            Highcharts g1 = new Highcharts("chart");
            g1 = Calcul_Global();
            Highcharts g2 = new Highcharts("chart");
            g2 = TB_Responsable();

            TableauDeBord model = new TableauDeBord(); 
            model.Charts = new List<Highcharts>();


            model.Charts.Add(g1);
           // model.Charts.Add(g2);

                return View(model);

        }
```

Any Help Please !

Answer (score 2):

From your code you have commented out // model.Charts.Add(g2); so it seems to me only one chart is added to the model

Make sure the chart names are unique in your method for generating each chart ie.  Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart2")

I imagine in your case the methods for generating the charts both read  Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need table or list to show more then one result:

```
<ul>
@foreach (Highcharts chart in Model.Charts)
{

       <li> @(chart)</li>

}
</ul>

//Or
<table>
@foreach (Highcharts chart in Model.Charts)
{

       <tr> <td>@(chart)</td></tr>

}
</table>
```